# Cordova $.ajax request wont work

Tags: ajax, cordova, request, whitelist

I am having issue with cordova ajax reuest.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: syncURL,
    data: (changed ? {start: changed + 1} : ''),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('Ajax success');
      callback(data);
    },
    error: function(model, response) {
      console.log('Ajax error');
      //app.notify(response.responseText, 'error');
      callback(null);
    }
  });
```

The program shows Ajax success in console log. I can see the content inside app while watching it on the browser with:

```
cordova serve
```

Unfortunately if i want to deploy to ios simulator or on android device,  the app wont load the content and get an empty json with no data.

What i am doing wrong. The simulator or android device got network connection.
I dont see nothing in log too.
Also added

`cordova plugins add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

cordova version is 7.1.0

Comment: have you tried deploying it on your phone having network connectivity ? Try putting <access origin="*" /> in config.xml this will allow request to any site. If You want  to restrict it to single site put the name of site instead of *. Hope that works

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into same error starting with [phonegap-vue-f7 template](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-vue-f7-blank) and using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) as Ajax library.

For same request to `http://my.domain.com/api/request` :

- returns code `200` with local `cordova serve` (`npm start` with [phonegap-vue-f7 template](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-vue-f7-blank))
- returns code `404` when I deployed to real device

The [phonegap-vue-f7 template](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-vue-f7-blank) furnish a pre-filled `config.xml` with this:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

at this point I had to install [`cordova-plugin-whitelist`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) to make it work.

So the [`cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) correctly configured seem to be the answer.

Answer (score -1):

not sure, but may be the `data:` value is not correct

```
data: (changed ? {start: changed + 1} : '')
```

What if you change to:

```
data: (changed ? '{start: changed + 1}' : '')
```